# Hit dropping objects from sky with bare hands or (object) with Kinect SDK for Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, nui

I am following a tutorial in a book called Learn the Kinect API by Rob Miles.
Basically, it's an augmented reality game where spiders fall from the top of the screen and you hit them with a Mallet. After following the tutorial and looking at the codes, I understand how the spiders fall and how their position are randomized etc.

I have problem understanding the mallet though, I wish to replace the mallet with an image of a basket instead.

This is how the code for the mallet looks like

```
Brush malletHandleBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
Brush malletHeadBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
float malletHandleLength = 100;
float malletHeadLength = 50;
System.Windows.Vector malletPosition;
float malletHitRadius = 40;
bool malletValid = false;

void updateMallet(Joint j1, Joint j2)
{
    // If Joint 1 (Right Wrist) or Joint 2 (Right Hand) is not tracked, we stop here
    if (j1.TrackingState != JointTrackingState.Tracked || j2.TrackingState != JointTrackingState.Tracked)
        return;

    // Get the start and end positions of the mallet vector
    ColorImagePoint j1P = myKinect.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToColorPoint(j1.Position, ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);
    ColorImagePoint j2P = myKinect.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToColorPoint(j2.Position, ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);

    int dX = j2P.X - j1P.X;
    int dY = j2P.Y - j1P.Y;

    System.Windows.Vector malletDirection = new System.Windows.Vector(dX, dY);

    if (malletDirection.Length < 1) return;

    // Convert into a vector of length 1 unit
    malletDirection.Normalize();

    // now set the length of the mallet 
    System.Windows.Vector handleVector = malletDirection * malletHandleLength;

    Line handleLine = new Line();

    handleLine.Stroke = malletHandleBrush;
    handleLine.StrokeThickness = 10;

    handleLine.X1 = j1P.X;
    handleLine.Y1 = j1P.Y;

    handleLine.X2 = j1P.X + handleVector.X;
    handleLine.Y2 = j1P.Y + handleVector.Y;

    //malletCanvas.Children.Add(handleLine);

    Line headLine = new Line();

    headLine.Stroke = malletHeadBrush;
    headLine.StrokeThickness = 50;

    System.Windows.Vector headVector = malletDirection * malletHeadLength;

    headLine.X1 = handleLine.X2;
    headLine.Y1 = handleLine.Y2;

    headLine.X2 = handleLine.X2 + headVector.X;
    headLine.Y2 = handleLine.Y2 + headVector.Y;
    //malletCanvas.Children.Add(headLine);

    malletPosition = new System.Windows.Vector(j1P.X, j1P.Y);

    malletPosition = malletPosition + (malletDirection * (malletHandleLength + (malletHeadLength / 2)));

    malletValid = true;
}
```

This is how the code for detecting if the mallet hits the objects looks like

```
// Declare Hit Vector for each Dollar Note
System.Windows.Vector _spiderHitVector = new System.Windows.Vector(malletPosition.X - _spiderCenterX, malletPosition.Y - _spiderCenterY);
```

Does anyone have any resources or give me some hints on how to work on this?

Comment: There is a demo app that comes with the SDK, Shape Game if I remember correctly, that describes how to work with the skeleton and interact with objects on the screen.  Have you had a chance to look over that code?

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey
Thank you! I looked at the code and indeed it is a very simple game with complex code. I have alot of trouble understanding all of the class files. If i can understand them all, I would have no trouble developing an even complex game than I can imagine when I was asking this question. Do you know of any resources which documents that sample game?